# Standard Lead Convert Action on custom Lightning Component

Tags: lightning, action, component, convert

Is there a way to call the existing standard action of Lead Convert inside a custom lighting component? I need to show a modal with some validations and if it seems correct by the user, click inside the modal the Convert standard action/button.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no interface to convert a Lead directly through Lightning Components.

However you can use your Apex controller for that. Here's the example how to convert Lead programmatically (full reference in [Apex Developer Guide: Converting Leads](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_convertlead.htm)):

```
Lead myLead = new Lead(LastName = 'Fry', Company='Fry And Sons');
insert myLead;

Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(myLead.id);

LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
```

Comment: Thank you!! I have a question based on your answer, the standard mapping functionality Map Lead Fields for custom fields it's 'fired' when I call convertLead() method? If on setup of lead objet I set x custom field on the lead object to map to x custom field on the oppty object this will work?

Comment: @Pablo Yes, the standard Lead Mapping logic should retain here.

Comment: Nice!! Thank you so much!!